# Not able to create the folder in external storage in marshmallow version

Tags: android

when I try to run this code in marshmallow the folder was not created..
the code is,I tried to run the same code its working fine except marshmallow

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/abcdefg");
    boolean success = false;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        success = folder.mkdir();
    }
    if (!success) {
        Log.d("", "Folder not created.");
    } else {
        Log.d("", "Folder created!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add below code in your activity for requesting runtime permission.
Your need to require `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to create folder(directory) in external storage.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE);//REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE=1111
        } else {
//Do your stuff here
            }
...

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

if(requestCode == REQUEST_FOR_STORAGE){
  //Do your stuff here
  }
 }
```

Hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

As marshmallow introduce Run time Permission you have to check for the permission

in run time. You can refer  here

1.https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

2.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZqDdvhTZj0

3.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C8lUdPVSzDk

You have to accept the STORAGE permission group from the user dynamically.
Go with the below link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html